# ${!prefix@} When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes

Tags: bash

I don't understand something the bash manual states about prefix parameter expansions.

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) says this:

> `${!prefix*}`
>   `${!prefix@}`
>
> Expands to the names of variables whose names
>   begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS special
>   variable. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double
>   quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.

When I execute this in a bash:

```
aaa=1
aab=2
aac=3
echo "${!aa@}"
```

The resulting output is this: `aaa aab aac`

That works as expected. However, the thing is that I get the same output when I use `echo "${!aa*}"`, and I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

`echo` joins all its arguments by a space and prints the result with a newline at the end. Using `printf` instead, you can see the difference clearly.

```
$ aaa=1
$ aab=2
$ aac=3
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${!aa@}"
<aaa>
<aab>
<aac>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${!aa*}"
<aaa aab aac>
```

Besides, while words are joined by the first character of `IFS` in the expansion of `*`; `IFS` is not honored at all when `@` is used.

```
$ IFS=,
$ echo "${!aa@}"
aaa aab aac
$ echo "${!aa*}"
aaa,aab,aac
```

Comment: Since variables can't have spaces anyway, I'm having a hard time thinking of a time when this makes a meaningful difference. Does anyone have any real world examples of when * might actually be preferred here?

Comment: @luckman212 I guess it's more about consistency than practicality. It's parallel with `$*` and `${array[*]}`.